# Insert multi rows in Adonisjs doesn't work

Tags: node.js, multidimensional-array, adonis.js

I have a problem when insert multi row using adonisjs. I have a form data in json array, when i'm try to insert this data using `request.post` to get array index it's doesn't work

this is my example of data in json array:

```
[
    {
        "id_cart" : "1",
        "id_product" : "1",
        "shop_id" : "2",
        "price" : "10000"
    },
    {
        "id_cart" : "1",
        "id_product" : "2",
        "shop_id" : "3",
        "price" : "20000"
    }
]
```

And then this is my controller:

```
const id_cart = nanoid(25)

const detailInfo = request.post(['id_cart','id_product','shop_id','price'])
const detail = new Detail()

detail.id_cart = id_cart
detail.id_product = detailInfo.id_product
detail.shop_id = detailInfo.shop_id
detail.price = detailInfo.price

await detail.save()
```

The result of column `id_product, shop_id, and price` is ***null***. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format your `JSON` input like this

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "id_cart": "1",
            "id_product": "1",
            "shop_id": "2",
            "price": "10000"
        },
        {
            "id_cart": "1",
            "id_product": "2",
            "shop_id": "3",
            "price": "20000"
        }
    ]
}
```

Insert into database as follows:

```
const productList = request.input("products");
await Product.createMany(productList);
```

Comment: how if i want to add new key value as `id` in json array out of productList input manually, but i have to generate it by my self(using nanoid)? i can't add that value because type of input is request.input()

Comment: @isnainibarochatun you can do with adonis hooks, read more here https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/database-hooks

Answer (score 1):

> The result of column id_product, shop_id, and price is null. What's wrong with my code?

Because the result has several objects.

You can use [Request collection](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/request#_request_collection) :

```js
// Example from official documentation
const users = request.collect(['username', 'age'])

// output
[{ username: 'virk', age: 26 }, { username: 'nikk', age: 25 }]

// save to db
await User.createMany(users)
```

#### OR

Fetch the complete result and process it with a loop

```js
const detailInfo = request.all() //Array
```

and create foreach

```js
detailInfo.rows.forEach(async (info) => {
    ...
})
```

Comment: i'm sorry but i try to using ```request.collect``` and ```createMany``` but all of data doesn't enter in db, and when try to using ```forEach``` it just error ***detailInfo.forEach is not a function***

Comment: detailInfo.forEach is not a function -> try detailInfo.rows.foreach(...)

Comment: For the method with `collect()` it's possible that foreign keys may cause problems

Comment: using ```rows.foreach``` still return ***Cannot read property 'foreach' of undefined***

Comment: is there any solution how to check where is the foreignkey's problem?

Comment: What's the result of request.all()?